# Null Pointer Exception When Trying to Use Persisted Table in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am creating "gpsLookUpTable" at the beginning and persisting it so that i do not need to pull it over and over again to do mapping. However, when i try to access it inside foreach i get null pointer exception. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Below is code snippets:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 

val conf = new SparkConf() ... 

val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(20)) 
val sqc = new SQLContext(sc) 

//////Trying to cache table here to use it below 
val gpsLookUpTable = MapInput.cacheMappingTables(sc, sqc).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2) 
//sc.broadcast(gpsLookUpTable) 
ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://localhost:9000/inputDirectory/") 
.foreachRDD { rdd => 
if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) { 

val allRows = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/supportFiles/GeoHashLookUpTable") 
sqc.read.json(allRows).registerTempTable("GeoHashLookUpTable") 
val header = rdd.first().split(",") 
val rowsWithoutHeader = Utils.dropHeader(rdd) 

rowsWithoutHeader.foreach { row => 

val singleRowArray = row.split(",") 
singleRowArray.foreach(println) 
(header, singleRowArray).zipped 
.foreach { (x, y) => 
///Trying to access persisted table but getting null pointer exception 
val selectedRow = gpsLookUpTable 
.filter("geoCode LIKE '" + GeoHash.subString(lattitude, longitude) + "%'") 
.withColumn("Distance", calculateDistance(col("Lat"), col("Lon"))) 
.orderBy("Distance") 
.select("TrackKM", "TrackName").take(1) 
if (selectedRow.length != 0) { 
// do something
} 
else { 
// do something
} 
} 
} }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are running in a cluster; your foreach will run as a closure on other nodes. The Nullpointer is raised because that closure runs on a node which doesn't have a initialized gpsLookUpTable. You did obviously try to broadcast gpsLookUpTable in

```
//sc.broadcast(gpsLookUpTable)
```

But this need to be bound to a variable, basically like this:

```
val tableBC = sc.broadcast(gpsLookUpTable)
```

in foreach, you would replace this:

```
foreach { (x, y) => 
///Trying to access persisted table but getting null pointer exception 
val selectedRow = gpsLookUpTable
```

with this:

```
foreach { (x, y) => 
///Trying to access persisted table but getting null pointer exception 
val selectedRow = tableBC.value
```

which effectively give you access to the broadcast value.

Comment: Much appreciated. I tired and it worked. However, the problem is increasing. The input file for gpsLookUpTable is around 11Mb and when i am performing the streaming operation the input file is around 3 Mb. The maping is taking more than 40 minutes in the setup of 16 cores and 64 GB (3 executors with 18GB each). The input in streaming is showing 11MB for each process (i guess thats the mapping file that is being accessed in every single foreach). Can you suggest any work around ?

Comment: Also the driver memory assigned is 10GB which should be more than enough to handle output data that will be around only 6 Mb, i guess.

Comment: The driver memory is not that relevant here. I would suggest using foreachPartition() too, that should parallelise more effectively

Comment: @ErikSchmiegelow can you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149997/spark-streaming-nullpointerexception-inside-foreachpartition