# Spark Streaming: NullPointerException inside foreachPartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job which reads from Kafka and does some comparisons with an existing table in Postgres before writing to Postrges again. This is what it looks like :

```
val message = KafkaUtils.createStream(...).map(_._2)

message.foreachRDD( rdd => {

  if (!rdd.isEmpty){
    val kafkaDF = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
    println("First")

    kafkaDF.foreachPartition(
      i =>{
        val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
          Map("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://...",
            "dbtable" -> "table", "user" -> "user", "password" -> "pwd" )).load()

        createConnection()
        i.foreach(
          row =>{
            println("Second")
            connection.sendToTable()
          }
        )
        closeConnection()
      }
    )
```

This code is giving me NullPointerException at the line `val jbdcDF = ...`

What am I doing wrong? Also, my log `"First"` works, but `"Second"` doesn't show up anywhere in the logs. I tried the entire code with `kafkaDF.collect().foreach(...)` and it works perfectly, but has very poor performance. I am looking to replace it with `foreachPartition`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear if there are any issues inside `createConnection`, `closeConnection` or `connection.sendToTable` but fundamental problem is an attempt to nest actions / transformations. It is not supported in Spark and Spark Streaming is not different.

It means that nested `DataFrame` initialization (`val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format ...`) simply cannot work and should be removed. If you use it as a reference it should be created at the same level as `kafkaDF` and refferenced using standard transformations (`unionAll`, `join`, ...).

If for some reason it is not an acceptable solution you can create plain JDBC connection inside `forEachPartition` and operate on PostgreSQL table (I guess it is what you're already do inside `sendToTable`).

Comment: I tried without the jdbcDF initialization and it's working, so definitely not an issue with any of the connection operations

Comment: I can't use an operator like join because I want to iterate over every row in kafkaDF and do some comparison with jdbcDF.

Comment: There is not much you can do here. You can either code your logic one way or another inside Spark (recommended approach) or create standard JDBC connection (not Spark `DataFrame`) and access data in PostgreSQL directly.

Comment: Check this question please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458109/null-pointer-exception-when-trying-to-use-persisted-table-in-spark-streaming?lq=1

Comment: They are talking about a solution to this. But I tried broadcasting the jdbcDF after creating it at the same level as kafkaDF, still giving me NPE

Comment: also @zero323 can you tell me why the logs inside foreachPartition wouldn't come?

Comment: I am running the job in a yarn cluster btw

Comment: Because broadcasting DataFrame won't work. I mean you can broadcast DataFrame object but it won't be accessible anyway.

Comment: can you take a look at the edited question? Appreciate the help

Comment: Could you post it as a separate question? It is not really related to the original issue and this type multiple problems questions are discouraged on SO.

Comment: Thanks, I have done it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216002/spark-streaming-how-can-i-add-more-partitions-to-my-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

As @zero323 correctly pointed out, you can't broadcast your jdbc connection around and you cannot create nested RDDs either. Spark simply does not support using sparkContext or sqlContext for that matter within an existing closure, i.e. foreachPartition, hence the null pointer exception.

The only way to solve this efficiently is to create a JDBC connection within foreachPartition and execute SQL directly on it to do whatever you intended and then use that same connection to write back the records.

As to your second, edited, question:

Change:

```
kafkaDF.foreachPartition(..)
```

to

```
kafkaDF.repartition(numPartition).foreachPartition(..)
```

where numPartition is the desired number of partitions. This will increase the number of partitions. If you have multiple executors (and multiple tasks per executor), these will run in parallel.

Comment: Can you take a look at this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216002/spark-streaming-how-can-i-add-more-partitions-to-my-dataframe