# Spark Streaming: How can I add more partitions to my DStream?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, partitioning, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark-streaming app which looks like this:

```
val message = KafkaUtils.createStream(...).map(_._2)

message.foreachRDD( rdd => {

  if (!rdd.isEmpty){
    val kafkaDF = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)

    kafkaDF.foreachPartition(
      i =>{
        createConnection()
        i.foreach(
          row =>{
            connection.sendToTable()
          }
        )
        closeConnection()
      }
    )
```

And, I run it on a yarn cluster using

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 5....
```

When I try to log `kafkaDF.rdd.partitions.size`, the result turns out be '1' or '5' mostly. I am confused, is it possible to control the number of partitions of my DataFrame? `KafkaUtils.createStream` doesn't seem to accept any parameters related to the number of partitions I want for the rdd. I tried `kafkaDF.rdd.repartition( int )`, but it doesn't seem to work either.

How can I achieve more parallelism in my code? If my approach is wrong, what is the correct way to achieve it?

Comment: Did you try the solution? Did it work for you?

Comment: I added more consumers and more partitions to Kafka topic. Performance is  better now. If you have some other suggestions to improve performance, let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spark Streaming, parallelism can be achieved in two areas: (a) the consumers/receivers (in your case the Kafka consumers), and (b) the processing (done by Spark).

By default, spark streaming will assign one core (aka Thread) to each consumer. So if you need more data to be ingested you need to create more consumers. Each consumer will create a DStream. You can then union the DStreams to get one large stream.

```
// A basic example with two threads for consumers
val messageStream1 = KafkaUtils.createStream(...) // say, reading topic A
val messageStream2 = KafkaUtils.createStream(...) // and this one reading topic B

val combineStream = messageStream1.union(messageStream2)
```

[Alternatively](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#level-of-parallelism-in-data-receiving), the number of receivers/consumers can be increased by repartitioning the input stream:

```
inputStream.repartition(<number of partitions>))
```

All the remaining cores available to the streaming app will be assigned  to Spark.

So if you have `N` cores (defined via the `spark.cores.max`) and you have `C` consumers you are left with `N-C` cores available for Spark.

```
#Partitions =~  #Consumers x (batch duration / block interval)
```

**block interval** = how long a consumer waits before it pushes the data it created as a spark block (defined as configuration `spark.streaming.blockInterval`).

Always keep in mind that Spark Streaming has two functions that constantly take place. A set of threads that read the current micro-batch (consumers), and a set of threads that process the previous micro-batch (Spark).

For more performance tuning tips please refer to [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#performance-tuning), [here](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/01/how-cigna-tuned-its-spark-streaming-app-for-real-time-processing-with-apache-kafka/) and [here](http://www.virdata.com/tuning-spark/).

Comment: I am running my app on a YARN cluster. I can't find the spark.cores.max property, but I am setting --executor-cores conf with my spark-submit command. So, does that mean the total number of cores available are (num-executors * executor-cores) ?

Comment: Also, can you provide an example or reference for creating more consumers  and doing union on them?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not an expert with YARN configurations, since I mostly work with standalone. `spark.executor.cores` should define the cores per executors. So `#Executors x spark.executor.cores = Total Cores`